# Javascript returning month as 9 where it is 10

Tags: javascript, firefox, internet-explorer

I'm building today's date using a onclick event in JavaScript. When i set the .value property with:

```
var now = new Date;
...Value = now.getMonth() + "/" + now.getDate() + "/" + now.getYear();
```

this produces: 9/9/2009
I am expecting: 10/9/2009

This happens in both IE and Firefox. The system time on my computer is correct. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's zero-based.  January is month 0.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getMonth.asp

Comment: Thanks, this was driving me nuts.

Answer (score 4):

[getMonth()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) starts at 0.

Answer (score 1):

The enumeration is 0 based.

0 = January
1 = Feb... etc

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, Indexing of months starts from `0-11`

i.e,

0 => january,1 => february, and so on...

For example,

If you want to get the month you can use `var.getmonth()` which will give you the month as `9` but display it as `october`.

I hope this helps:)